# How to send pdf file from Kuzzle plugin response?

Tags: javascript, kuzzle

I'm using Kuzzle as a backend for all my business logic for a mobile application and multiple websites.
On one website, I need to download a PDF containing multiple reports. To stay in the same architecture, I want to achieve this in a custom Kuzzle plugin.

The default response of a plugin is wrapped in a default HTML response , how ca I precise custom headers to send a file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Request.setResult](https://docs.kuzzle.io/plugins/1/constructors/request/#setresult) method to specify that your a returning a raw payload and to modify response headers.

Then simply return a `Buffer` containing the file content.

```
async sendPdf (request) {
  const file = fs.readFileSync('./file.pdf');
  request.setResult(null, {
    // Tell Kuzzle that this result will contain a raw payload
    raw: true, 
    headers: {
      // Set HTTP response headers
      'Content-Length': file.length.toString(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="file.pdf"`,
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
  );
  return file;
}
```

Of course this will only work with the HTTP or WebSocket protocol.